# Web API call wait for processing of another thread before responding

Tags: multithreading, asp.net-web-api

I have a windows service that has a self hosted web api. There is a single thread outside of the web api (call it Main thread) that is running who's sole responsibility is to check (somewhere) if there is data to be processed, sends it down stream to be processed, then put a response (somewhere) on the success (or not success) of the processing. That part of the design cannot be changed.

What I need to do is accept an HTTP request on the web api that will put the incoming data somewhere for the Main thread to pick up (I was thinking ConcurrentQueue), and then wait for that data to be processed before sending an HTTP Response.

The part I'm running into is how best for the HTTP request thread to wait for the data to be processed before responding? Doing a while loop watching for a response doesn't seem very efficient. My current thought is to setup a message bus where the HTTP request thread subscribes by passing a reference to its ManualResetEvent then waiting one. The Main thread will then publish to the bus after its done which will set the ManualResetEvent, allowing the HTTP request thread to grab the result and send an HTTP response.

Is using ManualResetEvents in this way a good idea? It feels like there should already be a way to handle this on a web api but I haven't found anything.

Comment: If multiple requests put something in the queue, how does the system know which request corresponds with an processed item?

Comment: I glossed over it but each one would have a unique id, then the response would have that same id as well.